# Why does bash insert additional quotes

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to pipe an expression including single quotes to a command, but bash inserts loads of extra quotes which breaks my command.  As a really simple example take:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
echo 'EXPRESSION' | more
```

which gives:

```
+ echo EXPRESSION
+ more
EXPRESSION
```

As I want the single quotes to be displayed, I must escape them:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
echo \'EXPRESSION\' | more
```

Which now gives me:

```
+ echo ''\''EXPRESSION'\'''
+ more
'EXPRESSION'
```

So within the script, I get this bizarre `''\''EXPRESSION'\'''` thing.  The command I am piping the expression to is an executable that interacts with a document management system, and expects a specific format—which includes single quotes around `EXPRESSION` and not `''\''` and `'\'''`.

Is there any way to stop bash from adding the additional quotes and backslashes? I've messed around with strings and `eval` etc., but have failed to get rid of those additional quotes.

Comment: `set -x` prints "words" with single quotes. That's what it does. They aren't really there. The `+ echo ''\''EXPRESSION'\'''` line is *not* in your script. It is the output from `set -x` (sent to `stderr` I believe unless you use `BASH_XTRACEFD` to set a different fd (in bash 4+)).

Comment: Look at the output of your `more` command: it's exactly what you're expecting, isn't it?

Comment: It's not very elegant to have the multiple single quotes like that, but Bash strips off the first two, the fourth and fifth, and the last two, leaving just the escaped ones.  It is the output you get if your single quoting code emits an open single quote and then starts looking at the string and finds an actual single quote.

Comment: Found the best discussion of this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26186942/bash-tokenizing-quoted-string-with-spaces-as-individual-words, in Charles Duffy's comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try it with double quotes like this,

```
echo "'EXPRESSION'"|more
```

**Output** will be,

```
'EXPRESSION'
```

Answer (score 0):

The /bin/bash -x is producing the top 2 lines. Your code produces the 3rd line. If you want you can just remove the -x and you should see it in a better way.

The above answer from Skynet works just fine, but with the -x option, it still shows 3 lines. It's just what the -x does.